# Google Chrome crashes while uploading - reading an excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, google-chrome

I have a system where you can upload an excel file and the web app stores this excel file on the server. After, the web app shows the content of the excel sheet in a grid list on the web page. The user clicks the items whatever need to be inserted into the database. So far so good.
Once the user submits the page, the web page reads the grid list and takes the items each by each and inserts into the database. And all good, the web page comes up with a result warning saying such as 50 items have been inserted successfully. It means the submit button task is done and the page is back from the server as the page does server-side process. However, once receiving the message, the explorer crashes and chrome turns offline with a sad face.
It just happens with Google Chrome. 
The excel file is a standard and a basic file which consists of max 100 records in it and probably including up to 20 columns. 
However, the case is not related to the uploading issue, coz the uploading progress is working well, the issue is to finalize the submission of the page from the server.
Any idea ?
I appreciate your time.

Comment: So.. do we get to see some code ?

Comment: the code involves some of db connection and hard to diverse it right now. what i can tell you is that the uploading and inserting case works very with any other browsers , however, not with Google chrome.